# How to add listener to JavaScript created templates

Tags: javascript, templates, events, handlebars.js

The user performs some action which triggers an XMLHttpRequest GET request which returns JSON which is used to populate some dialog module.

I've used [handlebarsjs](https://handlebarsjs.com/) which simplifies the creation of the HTML content, however, applying events to the newly created module is greatly complicated.

1. Is there a clean and maintainable method to add events to a Handlebars template? My current approach is to apply the events every time the module is opened which is less than ideal. If possible, it would be nice to render the DOM when loading the page but obviously without the JSON data which will populate the form, apply the events, and then update that values when the JSON is available.  For each loops, I guess only one loop element would initially be rendered and then it would be cloned as needed when getting the real JSON data.
2. If not, are there other JavaScript template libraries that provide this functionality?
3. If not, I will likely abandon JavaScript based templates.  Is there a leading other approach?

Comment: Use event delegation?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for React and Co.

Comment: @epascarello  I am researching event delegation right now and don't know how this will work.  According to https://javascript.info/event-delegation, they are applied to a common ancestor which hasn't been created, no?  Any additional thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisG  Would I just use React or use React with Handlebars?

Comment: Just React. It uses [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) which basically works like handlebars (insert variables into HTML).